# Importing GeoJSON file to React-Leaflet

Tags: json, reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I'm trying to import a GeoJSON file to react-leaflet like below:

```
import * as bar from "./data/bar.geojson";

...

function Foo() {
  return (
    <Map center={[...]} zoom={...}>
      <TileLayer
        ...
      />
      <GeoJSON data={bar} />
    </Map>
  );
}

export default Foo;
```

I'm getting "Error: Invalid GeoJSON object." for calling  `<GeoJSON data={bar} />`. I hardcoded the same GeoJSON data to this javascript file and it worked, so it must be the way of importing or handling the GeoJSON file that is causing a problem.

Does anyone have an idea of why I'm having an error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can import your geojson file like this:

```js
    import bar from "./data/bar.geojson";
```

And then use it as shown in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried yours but did not work, but it got fixed when I changed the file's extension from `.geojson` to `.json` (and of course changed the line to `import bar from "./data/bar.json";`). It's weird that it's not taking the `.geojson` format. I'm using `create-react-app` by the way.

Comment: I think create-react-app just add `/\.json$/` to json-loader in default webpack config. Badly there is no convenient way to override that config as vue-cli, except for eject all default configs.